# How does state transition matrix works

Tags: computer-science, control-theory, linear-control, kalman-filter

Suppose I have a simple vehicle moving in 2D. The state vector for the vehicle is X=[x y vx vy ax ay], that is, it contains the position (x,y), the velocity (vx, vy) and the acceleration (ax, ay) of the vehicle. assume the accelerations on x and y are constant and the linear model for a control system looks like this.

X(t) = AX(t-1) + Bu

What is the matrix A for the state vector x? I have look online by don't understand the examples. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First, let's start with some clean definitions and more standard notation. Usually, the dynamics will be described in continuous time as:

$ \dot{\mathbf{x}}(t) = A\mathbf{x}(t) + B \mathbf{u}(t)$

Or in discrete time as

$\mathbf{x}[k+1] = A\mathbf{x}[k] + b \mathbf{u}[k]$

Note that I used bold $\mathbf{x}$ for your state-vector, because usually we reserve capital letters for matrices. I'll be using continuous-time notation from now.
Now that we have that out of the way, what should we actually put in the state vector $x$?
Anything that is dynamic and changes with time. Almost always this goes up to, but *not including* accelerations! So for your case, that would mean:

$\mathbf{x} = \left ( \begin{array}{c} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \\ x_4 \end{array}  \right ) = \left ( \begin{array}{c} x \\ y \\ \dot{x} \\ \dot{y} \end{array}  \right )
$

This way, when we write the dynamics of our state vector, we get all the dynamics we want:

$
\dot{\mathbf{x}} = \left ( \begin{array}{c} \dot{x} \\ \dot{y} \\ \ddot{x} \\ \ddot{y} \end{array}  \right ) = \left ( \begin{array}{c} x_3 \\ x_4 \\ f_1 \\ f_2 \end{array}  \right ) 
$

Where I used $f_1,\,f_2$ as placeholders for those constants you said the acceleration should be. Note that in general, you would find some function $f(x)$ that describes your acceleration, and plug it in there.

So now, you want to write $\dot{\mathbf{x}}$ in terms of $\mathbf{x}$. So how do you do this?

$ \dot{\mathbf{x}} = \left ( \begin{array}{c} x_3 \\ x_4 \\ f_1 \\ f_2 \end{array}  \right ) = \left ( \begin{array}{cccc} 
? & ? & ? & ? \\ 
? & ? & ? & ? \\
? & ? & ? & ? \\
? & ? & ? & ? \\
\end{array} \right )\left ( \begin{array}{c} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \\ x_4 \end{array}  \right )
= \left ( \begin{array}{cccc} 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array} \right )\left ( \begin{array}{c} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \\ x_4 \end{array}  \right ) + \left ( \begin{array}{c} 0 \\ 0 \\ f_1 \\ f_2 \end{array}  \right )
$

So, notice that here I added a *feed-through* term containing $f_1, \, f_2$, because they are not dependent on your states! This is because you said the accelerations are constant, meaning that the dynamics of your velocities *do not* change with time, they stay constant! Well, then you don't need to put them in you state-vector huh? I'm guessing that you've just made a simplified version of the problem to post here, and you can actually choose what $f_1,\,f_2$ are. These would then actually be your control input $\mathbf{u}$, and instead of being a simple feed-through, they would go into the term $B\mathbf{u}$. The way of finding and writing $B$ is much the same, and I'll leave it to you.